# How to make RRDtool use commas instead of dots as decimal separators in graphs

Tags: perl, locale, rrdtool, setlocale

I'm using RRDtool through a Perl script (RRDs) to visualize temperature readings. As I want everything in the graph to be shown in Swedish (weekdays etc), I set the locale to **sv_SE.UTF-8** in my Perl script with:

```
use POSIX qw(locale_h);
setlocale(LC_ALL, "sv_SE.UTF-8");
```

RRDtool gets this, and prints weekday names in Swedish. However, numerical values that are written under the RRDtool graph with GPRINT use dots instead of commas as decimal separators (XX**.**xx), and I'm not sure why. In Swedish, commas should be used (XX**,**xx). I use GPRINT like this:

```
GPRINT:temp_out:MIN: Min\\: %6.1lf
```

I've tried setting LC_NUMERIC and LC_CTYPE to **sv_SE.UTF-8** as well, but without result. I've tried using **sv_SE.iso8859-1**, but no go. I've also read various printf documentation, but have yet to come up with a solution.

Has anyone managed to make RRDtool use commas instead of dots as decimal separators? Thanks!

**Edit:**

If I create the graph using `rrdtool graph` at the command line and have set `LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE`, I get commas as decimal separators. This leads me to believe that my Perl script doesn't pick up on my `setlocale`. Still investigating...

Comment: Which RRD Perl module are you using? RRD::Editor? RRDTool::Creator?

Comment: I'm using the RRDs module that is bundled with RRDtool and use RRDs::create and RRDs::graph to create the database and build my graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rrdtool is actually forcing `LC_NUMERIC` in multiple places to `'C'` in order to prevent stray commas from showing up in odd places ...

to see commas in generated charts, one would have to enhance this logic a bit further in `rrd_graph.c` to explicitly re-enable the users original `LC_NUMERIC` setting prior to rendering `GPRINT` statements.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Tobi. The weird thing is that I get commas in my graph when using rrdtool from the command line, so rrdtool seems to be following orders. However, when creating the graph using the Perl module RRDs, I get dots. A bit of googling would suggest that there might be something amuck with Perl's handling of LC_NUMERIC. The quest continues.

Comment: are you sure you are using the same version of rrdtool all the way ? the LC_NUMERIC enforcement is rather new.

Comment: Yes, I am using RRDtool 1.4.5 in both cases. In the end I went the quick and dirty route and edited rrd_graph.c to set `LC_NUMERIC` to `sv_SE` instead of `C`, and recompiled. Now I get commas as decimal separators when using the RRDs module as well. Not an elegant solution, but it works. Thanks so much for taking the time to answer!

Comment: note, that now the output of PRINT may be contain , too which might be not so optimal when it comes to parsing that if you are also extracting data using graphv for example.